# Cocoa screen saver config panel floating freely

Tags: cocoa, screensaver

I'm writing a screen saver using Cocoa's ScreenSaver API. It's compiled for 64-bit arch and I'm running it on Lion.

In order to enable configuration, I have added the following to the main view:

```
- (BOOL)hasConfigureSheet
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSWindow*)configureSheet
{
    if (configureSheet == nil) {
        if (![NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"WTConfigureSheet" owner: self]) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load config sheet");
            return nil;
        }
    }

    ScreenSaverDefaults *defaults =
        [ScreenSaverDefaults defaultsForModuleWithName: WTModuleName];

    backgroundColorWell.color = [defaults objectForKey: @"BackgroundColor"];
    lightLetterColorWell.color = [defaults objectForKey: @"LightLetterColor"];
    darkLetterColorWell.color = [defaults objectForKey: @"DarkLetterColor"];

    return configureSheet;
}
```

After installing the saver freshly, clicking "Options" makes the config sheet appear not as a sheet, but floating freely on the screen, without a border. Otherwise, it works correctly and disappears after being dismissed.

When I click "Options" a second time, the config sheet appears again, this time correctly as a sheet of the preferences window. It then immediately freezes, so that I can't click any of its controls.

Does anyone have an idea what causes this behavior?

Comment: I have since checked the Console output; nothing suspicious to be found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem as you today and it took me quite some time to figure this one out, so here's my solution:

I discovered that the `NSWindow` appears as soon as you call `loadNibNamed:owner:`. So there had to be some sort of mechanism to automatically open windows from nibs.

So I re-checked the nib and saw that there is an option called `"Visible At Launch"` on the attribute inspector pane which is checked by default.

The solution is very simple: just uncheck that checkbox and it works as expected.

I find it easy to overlook since you expect the window to open, but it actually opens twice (once automatically and a second time because System Preferences.app shows it as a sheet) which leads to the glitches.

Another problem that could happen, depending on how you defined the ivar / property on your class is that after the first close and re-open of the window it just freezes.
This is because per default the window releases itself when closed.

So be sure to also uncheck `"Release When Closed"` in interface builder.

Comment: You have just solved both of my problems! The window attached correctly once I cleared the `"Visible at Launch"` check mark; the freezing went away once I cleared the `"Release when closed"` one. Both make absolute sense when you think about it, but first you have to know they're there... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For this code to work as written, you need to create an IBOutlet of type `NSWindow*` named `configureSheet` in your main view's header file, save that file so Interface Builder can see the change, then load WTConfigureSheet.xib in Interface Builder and connect up the toplevel window component to Files Owner -> configureSheet.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out as soon as I get back to my Mac!

Comment: I've checked the code and the xib, it's set up the way you suggested.